# How to give an Epsilon-Delta proof of this limit $ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x} = \frac{1}{2} $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

How to give an Epsilon Delta proof of the following limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to 1}  \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: try applying the binomial fomula ( $(1-\sqrt(x))(1+\sqrt(x))$)

Comment: @FelixB. What I get is this: $\left|\frac{1-\sqrt(x)}{1-x} - \frac{1}{2}\right|$ using the binomial formula gives: $$ \frac{2 |1-x| - |1-x \sqrt(x)|}{2|1-x \sqrt(x)|} $$  Splitting those up in two and using $|x-1|< \delta$ gives: $$ \frac{2 \delta}{2|1-x \sqrt(x)|} - \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @FelixB. and working it out further gives:  $$ \frac{\delta}{|1-x \sqrt(x)|} - \frac{1}{2}$$ But then I get stuck again

Comment: $1 - x \sqrt x = (1 - \sqrt x)(1 + \sqrt x + x),$ but $(1-x)(1+\sqrt x)=1+\sqrt x-x-x\sqrt x$. How do you get $1 - x \sqrt x$ in the denominator?

Comment: @No.iD include your efforts in the question also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

observe $$ \dfrac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x} = \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}  $$
and you can now guess that the limit is 0.5 to prove find
$$\begin{align*} 
\left| \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} - \dfrac{1}{2}  \right| &= \left| \dfrac{1-\sqrt{x}}{2(1+\sqrt{x})} \right|\\
&= \left| \dfrac{x-1}{2(1+\sqrt{x})^2} \right|\\
&< \dfrac{|x-1|}{2}  \end{align*} $$
Now just take $\delta = 2\varepsilon$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its clear to me now!!

Comment: And blow my cover in the process!

Comment: did you mean that to read your answer for the steps in between @OscarLanzi

Answer (score 2):

1. Subtract $1/2$ from the function to get

$\dfrac{1-\sqrt x}{1-x}-\dfrac12=\dfrac{1-2\sqrt x+x}{2(1-x)}$

2. Apply $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ and $(c+d)(c-d)=c^2-d^2$ (do not be afraid to put in square roots for $b$ and $d$) to obtain

$\dfrac{1-2\sqrt x+x}{2(1-x)}=\dfrac{1-\sqrt x}{2(1+\sqrt x)}=\dfrac{1-x}{2(1+\sqrt x)^2}$

3. Argue that if $|1-x|=\delta$ is sufficiently small, then the denominator in the last expression given above will be greater than $2$.  Use this to find $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ so that the absolute value of $\dfrac{1-\sqrt x}{1-x}-\dfrac12=\dfrac{1-x}{2(1+\sqrt x)^2}$ will be $<\epsilon$.

> $\delta=2\epsilon$.  You may find a somewhat larger $\delta$ is allowed if you can sharpen the bound on the denominator in Step 3.